# UWP epPlus - choose directory to save

Tags: vb.net, uwp, epplus

I am making an application in vb using UWP and epPlus along with it to save the current database to an excel file. I would create a pop up dialog box that will allow the client to select the directory they want to save the excel file to. There isn't a "Savefiledialog" in UWP... Ideas?

**UPDATE**

I tried to use FileSavePicker: if I save it in the principal directory (C:\, Desktop, Documents ...) epPlus doesn't work, but if I save it in another directory (D:\, USB...) it workes... How can I save it in the principal directory?

I post my code here:

```
Private Async Sub ButtonXls_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RoutedEventArgs)

        OutputTextBlock.Text = ""
        Dim savePicker As FileSavePicker = New FileSavePicker()
        savePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.Desktop
        savePicker.FileTypeChoices.Add("Microsoft Excel", New List(Of String)() From {
            ".xlsx"
        })
        savePicker.SuggestedFileName = "Riepilogo_Test"
        Dim file As StorageFile = Await savePicker.PickSaveFileAsync()

        If file IsNot Nothing Then
            CachedFileManager.DeferUpdates(file)

            Dim ExcelPkg As ExcelPackage = New ExcelPackage()
            Dim wsSheet1 As ExcelWorksheet = ExcelPkg.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1")

            Using Rng As ExcelRange = wsSheet1.Cells(2, 2, 2, 2)
                Rng.Value = "Text file on Excel here"
                Rng.Style.Font.Size = 16
                Rng.Style.Font.Bold = True
                Rng.Style.Font.Italic = True
            End Using

            wsSheet1.Protection.IsProtected = False
            wsSheet1.Protection.AllowSelectLockedCells = False

            Dim filePath As FileInfo = New FileInfo(file.Path)
            ExcelPkg.SaveAs(filePath)

            Dim status As FileUpdateStatus = Await CachedFileManager.CompleteUpdatesAsync(file)

            If status = FileUpdateStatus.Complete Then
                OutputTextBlock.Text = "File " & file.Name & " was saved."
            ElseIf status = FileUpdateStatus.CompleteAndRenamed Then
                OutputTextBlock.Text = "File " & file.Name & " was renamed and saved."
            Else
                OutputTextBlock.Text = "File " & file.Name & " couldn't be saved."
            End If
        Else
            OutputTextBlock.Text = "Operation cancelled."
        End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: [FileSavePicker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileSavePicker) Class. See the (official) [Windows-universal-samples](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples) repo for more interesting stuff.

Comment: Don't forget to handle the current User (see the [FileSavePicker.CreateForUser()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.pickers.filesavepicker.createforuser#Windows_Storage_Pickers_FileSavePicker_CreateForUser_Windows_System_User_) method, for example). Consider that UWP is more *sensible* when it comes to access rights (or user/app rights in general).

Comment: Please, can I have an example of this method? :/

Comment: Hi, have you tried to add a `Documents` capability? Here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#restricted-capability-list). You can add `<uap:Capability Name="documentsLibrary"/>` in your `Package.appxmenifest` (open with code) -> `Capabilities` tag

Comment: Hi! Yes but it doesn't work

Comment: @mcentu91 Hi, UWP has stricter permissions for file io through the path. epPlus may internally write files through file path, and will report errors when it comes to folders with high permission requirements. You can check out this document for [UWP file access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions). You can try the `broadFileSystemAccess` mentioned at the end of the document, which might help you. Or you can modify the source code of [epPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) and add the `SaveAs` method based on `StorageFile`.